# Getting Bundle key?

Tags: java, bundle

I want to make process based on key values.
How can I do?
Thanks

```
        private Bundle bundle;
    public void add(){              
            bundle.putString("a", "Name");
            bundle.putString("b", "Surname"); //Set value
}

bundle.getString("a"); // Get value
```

Comment: Could you give us more context? What's a Bundle here?

Comment: How can I get key parameter value? I want to do different prosess based on key value.

Comment: does each key have a value? can each key only appear once? can each key have more than one value associated with it? Please edit your question to include more detail on what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I want to do something exactly like this: I want to keep the errors that occur in app with different key values​​ and I want to display the error message in a class.

Answer (score 0):

All you want is a [`HashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). No?